# Configure Eclipse to use bash login shell for Cygwin toolchain

Tags: eclipse, bash, cygwin

I have a custom Makefile project in Eclipse and although the build does get run in a Cygwin shell...  it does not seem to be a login shell (`bash --login`) as it doesn't set my environment variables like running `cygwin.bat` does.

Where in Eclipse can I change the shell command so that it will be a login shell?

Answer (score 2):

What you actually aim with *bash --login* are your settings from */etc/profile*.

Under UNIX you normally have only one login shell and so these settings are inherited by all other shells. Under Windows any Bash window is an isoloated login shell, which leads to missing environment settings when running Bash from tools that run *bash* simply as command processor.

I had a similar problem with Emacs compile feature. The best solution under Windows is to set the environment variable `BASH_ENV` to a script. Bash will execute this script when started without *-i* or *--login*, so that */etc/profile* is not run.  Hence the script will setup Bash for non-interactive, non-login shells.

Example:

```
BASH_ENV=%USERPROFILE%\.bash_env
```

as user environment variable. The least thing to do in this script is to set *PATH* as in */etc/profile*:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:${PATH}"
```

Check the path-settings in `/etc/profile` as it is created by Cygwin's *setup.exe*. You may also copy settings from `~/.bashrc` or source this script.

Hope this helps.